# Hyperledger Explorer Error 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: service protos.Endorser

Tags: postgresql, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to run the Hypeledger Explorer for my blockchain network. I have followed the instructions almost word for word using the [Hyperldger Explorer](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer)
But anytime I do the final call: ./start.sh --- I get a litany of errors

`error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
    at new createStatusError (/home/ubuntu/bludev/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/ubuntu/bludev/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15`

`error: [Client.js]: Failed Installed Chaincodes Query. Error: Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
    at new createStatusError (/home/ubuntu/bludev/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at /home/ubuntu/bludev/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15`

...

And so on. For more info I am using 
nodejs 6.9 and PostgreSQL 9.5. This is the way my config.json file looks:

```
{

"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "peerOrg1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/home/ubuntu/bludev/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/ubuntu/bludev/hlcomposer/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/ubuntu/bludev/hlcomposer/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    }
},
"host": "localhost",
    "port": "3000",
    "channel": "mychannel",
    "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
    "eventWaitTime": "30000",
    "pg": {
            "host": "12.109.99.233",
            "port": "3000",
            "database": "fabricexplorer",
            "username": "postgres",
            "passwd": "password1"
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your hyperledger network does not have any endorser in network.

try first-network sample from official fabric-samples folder, rebuild the explorer and then try again.